# How to intent to url from non activity class?

Tags: android, url, android-intent

Hi I am working with android. I used an intent to the google play using the following code

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  intent.setData(Uri.parse(MyURL));
  startActivity(intent);
```

Now How can I use the same method from a non activity class ??

Answer (score 0):

you can send your Activity Context to your non Activity class then use your method.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(MyURL));
activity_Context.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

.Pass the context to the non-activity class by passing  `this` .

. Receive the context from the class
. Use the context stored (as `mContext` here)to start Activity :

```
   access_specifier  return_type   function_name (Context mContext)
    {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
     intent.setData(Uri.parse(MyURL));
     mContext.startActivity(intent)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remind that whenever you'r calling any function or method from `Non-Activity` class at that time you need to use `Context` of that class. Suppose

```
Context mContext;

public YourClass(Context ctx){

 mContext = ctx;

}
```

Now using of this `mContext` variable

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(MyURL));
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: i don't know cause of these repetitive answers! your answer is just what i mentioned.

Comment: @Arash This question has a unique answer and i have mentioned properly.

Comment: This is not a unique answer, and you certainly haven't described it very well.  Though you have shown a bit more of the mechanism than Arash did by explicitly showing a variety of constructor which accepts and stores a context passed in from somewhere else.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Answer depends on different users. I have posted answer what i known so there is no any issue.

Comment: The point is that your solution is the same as Arash's however you show more of the supporting details.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Yes. I am trying to say that one.

Comment: anyway it clears error but doesnot goes to the link :(

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(MyURL));
MyClass_Activity.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: what is MyClass_Activity ??